# how to configure selenium(webdriver)framework under eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i have readymade framework for selenium(webdriver)(datadrievnfreamework). Please tell me how to configure that framework under eclipse . please help me out

Comment: Google's first page gave me [this](http://diveintotesting.com/2013/02/19/selenium-web-driver-setup-using-eclipse-and-java/). Please put some efforts next time...

Comment: i how how to configure selenium under eclipse but im asking how to setup framework

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to exactly do. Can you modify your question and explain us about this more briefly..?

Comment: i want to fetch data from excel and read it , and we have to store that excel file, property file,config, etc files  under my project, (elcipse)how to set up the framework for that . ??????

Comment: @user2493172 if you'd led with your actual question, as you made clear in your comment, you may have received help a lot faster. There is not a lot from your title to suggest that this is the assistance you required.

Answer (score 0):

Put some efforts to search in Google.

Kindly refer the eclipse guide for setting the environment. For some basic setup, refer:
http://selftechy.com/2011/03/18/selenium-setting-up-selenium-eclipse

For parameterization, refer:
http://diveintotesting.com/2013/02/23/parameterizing-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-testng-a-data-driven-approach/

For further coding using webdriver, refer:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to configure selenium webdriver with eclipse

1. Download latest selenium jar zip files for JAVA form
   http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
   (http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-java-3.4.0.zip)
2. Extract zip file
3. Open Eclipse > Add New java Project by right click on left side
   package explorer
4. Right Click on package explorer > NEW > Java Project
5. Right click on project > Select properties > Select Java Build Path
6. Select Libraries tab > Click on Add External JARs
7. Import all jar by selecting form extracted selenium jar folder & click on OK

Note - Every Time you need to follow same process ,  when you create new Selenium Automation project